# Boundaries for area with double integration.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have to find the area using double integral for the domain bounded by 
$$y^2=x$$
and
$$y=x-2$$
Now, I want to find my integral boundaries:
I did $y=x^2, y=x+2$, solved this system and get
$$x_1=1,\quad x_2=4.$$ 
Now I don't know how should my integration boundaries should be for $dy$ is from $x-2$ to $\sqrt{x}$ or from $\sqrt{x}$ to $x-2$

$$\int_?^?\int_{1}^4{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y$$

Comment: Is it $y=x+2$ or $y=x-2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x=y-2$, solving $y^2=y+2$ you get $y_1=-1\quad y_2=2 $. Your integral becomes: 
$$\int_{-1}^{2}\int_{y^2}^{y+2}dx dy\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Answer:  you can solve it either way, the iterated integral dydx is a little bit more complicated, it will help if you draw the region. For the values of x from 0 to 1 the limits of y runs from $-\sqrt{x}$ to $\sqrt{x}$ and for the values of x from 1 to 4 the limits of y runs from $x-2$ to $\sqrt{x}$  So the integral becomes

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} dydx + \int_{1}^{4}\int_{x-2}^{\sqrt{x}} dydx$$.

This is the same as 
$$\int_{-1}^{2}\int_{y^2}^{y+2} dxdy$$

Both of them evalute to 4.5.

Thanks

SatisY